# Retrieving data stored as image as string in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to retrieve an xml file stored as image data in SQL Server.

I am using this query -

```
select 
    convert(varchar, convert(binary, zd.validcontent)) 
from 
    zonedata zd
join 
    contentitem ci on zd.itemid = ci.itemid
where 
    id = @dpathid
```

I get text but but the result returns only a small portion of the xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2003. Valid years are 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014 (*CTP*)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry my bad.

Comment: If you use `CONVERT(VARCHAR ....` without **explicitly specifying a length** for the `VARCHAR`, you get 30 characters. It's recommend best pracise to ***always*** explicitly specify a length for a `VARCHAR` - in `CONVERT`, when used as a parameter - everywhere, really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`char` and `varchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> **char**  [ ( *n* ) ]
>
> **varchar**  [ ( *n* | **max** ) ]
>
> When *n* is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When *n* is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

So, please specify a suitable length (e.g. `max` as shown in @Devart's answer, or any more appropriate value)

Answer (score 21):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), zd.validcontent))
FROM zonedata zd
JOIN contentitem ci ON zd.itemid = ci.itemid
WHERE ID = @dpathid
```

Comment: Thanks Devart, this is the solution that I needed.